# Business Objects pulling SQL freehand from someone else's Made web Intelligence report

Tags: scripting, reporting, business-objects

I am looking to get the SQL code from another report within my organization. When I go to get the SQL code. Data Access>Data Provider> EDIT.. the edit button is greyed out.. I am not looking to manipulate the query just looking to pull the Script. Is there any work around to this? Hopefully there is another option rather than just contacting IT.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the report to your own Favorites folder; you should be able to edit the query in the copied report.

If not, then it's likely that you don't have access to the data source (ex., universe) that the report was created from.

Alternatively, you can add a cell in the report itself to display the SQL.  Create a blank cell, then add the following formula.  You need to reference any object in the query in order to first get the name of the data provider.  In my example below, I have an object in my report named "Dept Name":

```
=DataProviderSQL(DataProvider([Dept Name]))
```

Comment: That is a fantastic tip!